# Set anchor point for image scaling?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to give an image inside a div an anchor point to control the scaling when resizing the browser window? So instead it being centered for example the whole time, another point of the image should act as anchor point and the image would resize around that point. Or is it possible to make the image move to the left when resized? Is this possible using CSS only? 
CSS

```
.banner {
    background-color:grey;
    height:734px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden
}

.banner img {
    width: 1920px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="source" alt="bannerimage">
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide html

Comment: its just the basic two lines

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image2 check this help you. If possible give us desire output what exactly you need. Description is not clear.